# Tuned-admin profile realtime does not work for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, realtime

I would isolate cores using tuned realtime profile.

I have modfiled `/etc/tuned/realtime-variables.conf`

```
# Examples:

isolated_cores=0-7

#
#
# Uncomment the 'isolate_managed_irq=Y' bellow if you want to move kernel
# managed IRQs out of isolated cores. Note that this requires kernel
# support. Please only specify this parameter if you are sure that the
# kernel supports it.
#
isolate_managed_irq=Y
```

and then run `tuned-admin profile realtime`

however, tuned does not add isolcpus to boot command line.

After reboot, I can still see processes scheduled to core 0-7.

Answer (score 1):

The `tuned` software is written for RedHat and there are a number of bugs with the package ported for Ubuntu.  This looks like another one, but there may be a work around.

I duplicated your attempt and looked in `/var/log/tuned/tuned.log`.  I see the lines

```
2023-07-25 22:31:07,931 INFO     tuned.plugins.plugin_bootloader: installing additional boot command line parameters to grub2
2023-07-25 22:31:07,932 ERROR    tuned.plugins.plugin_bootloader: cannot find grub.cfg to patch, you need to regenerate it by hand by grub2-mkconfig
```

Looking at the [tuned source code](https://github.com/redhat-performance/tuned/blob/v2.15.0/tuned/consts.py#L27) I believe `tuned` is looking for the file `/etc/grub2.cfg`.

If I symlink this file then the profile does apply.

```
ln -s /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/grub2.cfg
tuned-adm profile realtime
```

Now the `isolcpus` argument is in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.  I think the only file directly modified by `tuned` is `/etc/tuned/bootcmdline`.